# Remapping X key to Alt + Right

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, remap

I am trying to X key to Alt + Right but I can't seem to get it right. This is what I have so far:

`z::Send {Alt Right}`

If I use it in VLC it doesn't have the same effect as if I press Alt+Right manually. I suspect it has to do with not being able to have alt pressed and then press right slow enough for VLC to get it.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `{Alt Right}` is not a valid key name,  every key should be enclosed in its own brackets. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: Also tried with ! as Alt. Specifically if I write "z::Send {!}{Right}" what I get instead is first a "!" is written and then right key is pressed. "z::Send {!Right}" doesn't do it either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the alt modifier outside of brackets.

```
z::Send !{Right}
```